# DynamicModule endlessly updating unexpectedly

Tags: dynamic

I've encountered an error using `DynamicModule` to show results of some numeric or symbolic solving algorythms (I've tried `NMaximize`, `Minimize`, `NMinValue`). If a dynamic function (here it is named `happa`) uses such an algorithm, and influences the output, `DynamicModule` updates continuously. The following examples demonstrate the problem.

Can somebody explain why example #3 updates continuously, without any input?

1. This example behaves as expected, printing "oops" once per every interaction with `SetterBar`:

   ```
   DynamicModule[{happa, dummy},
     happa[] := (dummy + 2);
     {SetterBar[Dynamic[dummy], Range[5]], Dynamic[Print["oops"]; happa[]]}]
   ```
2. Now add a pointless algorithm in `happa` definition. This example behaves unexpectedly, printing "oops" twice per every interaction with SetterBar, suggesting that it updates twice:

   ```
   DynamicModule[{happa, dummy},
     happa[] := (Minimize[{Sin[x], x >= 0 && x <= 1}, x]; dummy + 2);
     {SetterBar[Dynamic[dummy], Range[5]], Dynamic[Print["oops"]; happa[]]}]
   ```
3. Now add **two** pointless algorithms in `happa` definition. This example behaves unexpectedly, printing "oops" continuously, even without any interaction, suggesting that it is updating continuously:

   ```
   DynamicModule[{happa, dummy},
     happa[] := 
       (Minimize[{Sin[x], x >= 0 && x <= 1}, x]; 
        Minimize[{Sin[x], x >= 0 && x <= 1}, x]; dummy + 2);
     {SetterBar[Dynamic[dummy], Range[5]], Dynamic[Print["oops"]; happa[]]}]
   ```
4. Now declare `happa` as a variable with delayed evaluation. This example behaves as expected, printing "oops" once per every interaction with `SetterBar`:

   ```
   DynamicModule[{happa, dummy},
     happa := 
       (Minimize[{Sin[x], x >= 0 && x <= 1}, x]; 
        Minimize[{Sin[x], x >= 0 && x <= 1}, x]; dummy + 2);
     {SetterBar[Dynamic[dummy], Range[5]], Dynamic[Print["oops"]; happa]}]
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The continuous retriggering of dynamics in these examples is a bug.

It has been fixed, as of *Mathematica* 9.0.